# Add icon as button in each row of angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material version 9.2.4
I have a table in html. The table has been displayed properly. But I want to add an icon as button in each row of the table.
The table datas are coming from a rest api while I want to use same icon(say Delete icon) in each row of the table.

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="employeeData" class="mat-elevation-z8">
<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> NAME </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="phoneNumber">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> PHONE NUMBER </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.phoneNumber}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="emailId">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EMAIL ID </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.emailId}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Symbol Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="dateOfBirth">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DATE OF BIRTH </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dateOfBirth }} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Delete Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="deleteEmployee">
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <!-- <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Example icon button with a vertical three dot icon"> -->
      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    <!-- </button> -->
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

I am not able to get the delete icon. the table looks like this
[image]

I want to display the delete icon after the column date of birth.
What I am missing?

Comment: You need to include the `deleteEmployee` column in the `displayedColumns` array. The columns will be displayed in the same order as in the `displayedColumns` array. So make sure you place the `deleteEmployee` in the appropriate position.

Comment: matColumnDef="deleteEmployee" is only valid when "deleteEmployee" will be present in the backend response. But I dont have any such like that.

Comment: I want to simply include an icon in each row of the table

Comment: `matColumnDef="deleteEmployee" is only valid when "deleteEmployee" will be present in the backend response.` No, this is not correct. You can add any number of empty new columns. The only condition is they have to be present in the `displayedColumns` array. If you are getting this array from the backend then just add a new item to it.

Answer (score 9):

Add the matColumnDef 'deleteEmployee' to displayedColumns's Array in your ts file.

For Example:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'deleteEmployee'];
```

and your html file

```
<!-- Delete Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="deleteEmployee">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
       <button mat-icon-button color="primary" aria-label="Example icon button with a home icon">
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```